# Use of "the" in Indian English

Tags: definite-articles, subcontinental-english, concision

The word "the" in Indian English seems to have a different function than in American English, and I'd like to understand it better.  The first sentence of [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) demonstrates what I mean:

> Today in this article I would discuss about the Database Mail which is used to send the Email using SQL Server.

In American English, I'd write:

> In today's article I will discuss Database Mail, which is used to send email using SQL Server.

Is that considered wrong or overly concise in Indian English?

What is the use of the additional "the"s in the original? Is this a typical pidgin construct or specific to Indian English?  What rule of American English makes this sound awkward to my ears?

Comment: It is not the case with every Indian. It must be either mother tongue influence or he is trying emphasize on the topic- database mail; I don't get "send *the* email", this is funny.

Comment: If you noticed, many Indians also use *-ing* everywhere.

Comment: It's simply "broken" English, as any Indian would tell you. The same "anomaly" is made by many native Hebrew speakers when speaking English. Russell Peters would be able to teach you how to speak such Indian-styled street English, "some body's gonna get the hurt."

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yVcePxjFujs

Comment: You're overthinking it. `The` doesn't have a Hindi equivalent. It's hard for a new speaker to determine where to put it and sometimes they overdo it. The AmE version wouldn't be wrong in InE because as far as I know, InE doesn't have separate rules for `the`. Also, please don't consider a single email as representative of InE. If you find it in a reputed Indian publication/periodical, that's another matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For most Indian people, English is not their first language so they have a tendency to translate words from their mother tongue on the fly, which leads to some funny examples like "passing out" of college or staying up till 2 AM to "work hardly" on a problem.

The first sentence that you gave can be very easily translated into Hindi (the most widely-spoken Indian language) while the second one cannot be translated as easily.

Comment: This is incorrect: [*level best*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107654?redirectedFrom=level+best#eid39373083) is not Indian, but (originally, non-native-)American.  The OED attests its use since 1851, but it is no longer restricted to America.

Comment: *Passing out* is certainly used of military academies. But not so much of academic institutions, no.

Comment: In India, it is commonly used for academic institutions.

Comment: Can you give some sources where *work hardly* is used as depicted in your example? Cause I have never had such a usage encounter.

Comment: http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070602022222AAkmo2K

Answer (score 2):

The two topics that I have found more difficult than others are THE USES OF THE and THE USES OF TENSES.
Once, so many years ago, I tested people including Professors of English whom I know personally with the aim of knowing whether they are good at using THE correctly. Unfortunately, none of them passed the test.
The English that we, Indians, use is different in several aspects from British and American English. We pronounce a large number of English words incorrectly, we make grammar and usage mistakes, we use words that are understood only by Indians. For example, instead of the American RESUME (and the British CURRICULUM VITAE), etc. Indians use BIODATA widely. Indians use LAKH to mean "one hundred thousand", and CRORE to mean "ten million".
Indians usually do not mind the omission or insertion of THE in a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with @Xitij, both the sentences have the same meanings when (easily) translated in Hindi, with minor sentence structural difference.

**[Pinal Dave](http://www.linkedin.com/in/pinaldave)**, the author of the OP's quoted article, is a [USC](http://colleges.usnews.rankingsandreviews.com/best-colleges/university-of-southern-california-1328) graduate, (which means he cleared his GRE, which means he definitely understands the use of 'the' ).
But, in-spite of knowing the correct usage, I feel his usage is influenced from the language of his ethnic group as pointed out by @Fr0zenFyr. And that would also be the **ans to the OP.**

And as in the wiki entry about [First language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_language) being the language(s) a person starts learning from the very beginning, in India students learn it from the very first day they go to school (not counting the English they learn at home), along Hindi. Hence for most Indians Hindi and English are both their first languages.
What you ( Xitij) are suggesting would be valid, if you differentiate word 'Mother Tongue' as one's ethnic group's language. This [newspaper article](http://www.indiatribune.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=9705:india-worlds-second-largest-english-speaking-country&catid=107:coverpage&Itemid=471) tells us that India has the second largest English speaking population in the world (mostly due to the high population in itself).

[image]
And I did not highlight the minor structural difference at the end of the sentence.

Comment: Are you sure that the two sentences written in Devanagari script are grammatically correct? In particular, the verb at the end seems to need a plural subject, and if the verb remains unchanged, the translation into English would result in something like "In today's article, _we_ will discuss..." not "In today's article, _I_ will discuss..."

Comment: The google translator does a literal translation. I am trying to highlight the usage of 'the' as interpreted in Hindi with google translator. Which is also the OPs main concern